# connecting refused for web socket socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am loading my scripts using

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="/js/chat.js"></script>
```

My chat.js script is :

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function(){
  var chatForm = document.forms.chatForm;
  if (chatForm) {
    var chatUsername = document.querySelector('#chat-username');
    var chatMessage = document.querySelector('#chat-message');

    chatForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
      console.log("working")
      //prevents page from reloading
      e.preventDefault();
      //emit the message with the socket
      socket.emit('postMessage',{
        username: chatUsername.value,
        message: chatMessage.value,
      });

      chatMessage.value='';
      chatMessage.focus();
    });//chatform event

    socket.on('updateMessages', function(data) {
      showMessage(data);
    });//update messages
  }//chatForm
})

function showMessage(data) {
  var chatDisplay = document.querySelector('.chat-display')
  var newMessage = document.createElement('p');
  newMessage.className = 'bg-success chat-text';
  newMessage.innerHTML = '<strong>' + data.username + '<strong>:</strong>' + 
    data.message
  chatDisplay.insertBefore(newMessage, chatDisplay.firstChild);
}
```

My app.js file uses:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000 );


var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

io.attach(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("user connected");
  socket.on('postMessage', function(data) {
    io.emit('updateMessages', data);
  });
});
```

I am getting the following errors in my console and have no idea how to fix them. Somebody please help! [image]

The server is listening on port 3000. My console is saying that there is an unhandled 'error' event

Comment: that generally means that there is no server on localhost on that port

Comment: yeah you only have a client here... or did you not include the server code?

Comment: is the server not localhost:3000 by default?

Comment: my app.js file uses app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000 );

Comment: var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

io.attach(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("user connected");
  socket.on('postMessage', function(data) {
    io.emit('updateMessages', data);
  });
});

Comment: it’s hard to read that.. are you able to edit and update the original posy with the server code? thanks

Comment: @mad.meesh yes I updated the post

Comment: what OS is that? ping localhost, what you get?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js file, you should connect socketIO before listening:

```
const socketIO = require('socket-io');

const io = socketIO(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("user connected");
  socket.on('postMessage', function(data) {
    io.emit('updateMessages', data);
  });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000 );

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Let try it, because I think after listening, everything won't work. We should connect socketIO before listening.